# jQuery toggle is not really working

Tags: jquery, toggle

On [this site](https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com), I have the following `<script>`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu-item-63>a').click(function(){
            $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
        }
    }};
</script>
```

And the following menu:

```
<ul id="menu-bottom-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-56"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-63"><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-55"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-54"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/privacy-terms">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-53"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/news-events">News &amp; Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the following div:

```
<div id="newsletter-container">
    <div id="newsletter">
        ...etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I click on `Subscribe` in the bottom menu, the toggle does not work - `#newsletter-container` does not display.

Comment: Change `}};` to `});`. Also please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323579/11683.

Comment: it is better to provide a small demo than providing a link. also provide **ALL RELEVANT CODE TO OP**

Comment: @Steve in your live site you have a WP website with at least 10 plugins that load each one the javascript file that it wants/needs. Try to determine that you don't have conflicting libraries loading. Additionally you load all js files in head section and no defer or async attributes are used. Try to use WP total cache or some similar plugin that manipulates js and css files binding them together. But to tell you the truth the best way in such matters is to do it on your own and with no plugin.

Comment: @Steve.. in other words your problem is due to the way you load javascript files. The actual order of the scripts is causing you the problem, or some library is conflicting another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using jQuery in WordPress...

In WordPress `$` won't work out of the box to avoid conflicts...

You need to use following code...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#menu-item-63>a').click(function(){
        $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
    });
});
```

Basically you start your jQuery doc ready function with `jQuery` instead of `$` and require `$` as parameter. Since jQuery object is passed as parameter to this function you should be able to use jQuery with whatever you name the parameter.

Hope that helps ;)

**EDIT**

Works like a charm now,

Used these styles to aid visibility...

```
#newsletter-container {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 970px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Shramee. Yes it helps a lot. Thank you. I had to replace all $ with jQuery to avoid an error.  `#newsletter-container` now exists on my site, on line 421 I believe. Unfortunately the toggle() is not occurring. `#newsletter-container` does not display when clicking `#menu-item-63>a`

Comment: Hi, link you shared to live site... https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/, still doesn't seem to have `#newsletter-container`, you may be using a hook which might not be getting called...

Comment: Search for `newsletter-container` in the source and you'll find `<!-- #main -->
<div id="newsletter-container">
 <div id="newsletter">`

Comment: Ohh... yeah, it is there :) Sorry... And it is appearing too... However, seems like gravity form is not rendered...

Comment: Now includes a screenshot after clicking Subscribe and some sample styles to make it look like a dialog...

Comment: Hi Shramee. The plugin was deactivated. Activated now. Your code works perfectly. I wish to have `#newsletter-container` at the same location as the newsletter box when clicking "subscribe" @ [http://www.paspaley.com/](http://www.paspaley.com/).

Comment: I tried adding: `jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ('#newsletter-container').offset().top
   }, 1000);` to your code to see if I could scroll to `#newsletter-container` but this does not work.

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error. The click event and doc ready have not been closed properly:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#menu-item-63>a').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault(); // use this to stop the default behavior of anchor.
             $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
         }); // here
     }); // here too
```

Comment: I can't get this code to work on the [live site](https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com)

Comment: Yes: `TypeError: $ is not a function` (line 226). Line 226 is `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Ohh!!! As you have used jQuery then you need to load jQuery lib before this script.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks Jai. I have enqueued/added Jquery, and the same error remains... ? [> See live site](https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com)

Comment: @Steve you are getting a 404 error on your js, which means it isn't even loading/finding it. You need to fix that and then it will work

Comment: @Steve the one that isn't loading is https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/wp-content/themes/WCM010017/js/megnor/carousel.min.js?ver=4.5.2

Comment: @RachelGallen `/WCM010017/js/megnor/carousel.min.js?ver=4.5.2` is not required for Jquery to work, and is not related to the question. :-)

Comment: @Steve it looks like its required for the slider, cos when i inspected the Subscribe element, it showed me that error. Regardless, you shouldn't have 404s on your page anyway!

Comment: @RachelGallen the slider is controlled by Slider Revolution Wordpress plugin, not the theme's default slider. The code posted by @Jai that I used in that page (line 226) is what generates the error `staging.venusanddiamonds.com/:226 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`. 

The error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (): https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/wp-content/themes/WCM010017/js/megnor/carousel.min.js?ver=4.5.2` is caused by an error in the commercial theme `WCM010017` and not related to the issue at hand. :-)

Comment: This code won't work with WordPress... WordPress doesn't allow using `$` for `jQuery`... Check my answer here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562117/jquery-toggle-not-working/37741025#37741025

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-63>a').click(function(){
        $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fix your syntax error of jQuery and need to load jQuery in your page.
Check the below working code snippet.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu-item-63>a').click(function(){
            $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-bottom-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-56"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-63"><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-55"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-54"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/privacy-terms">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-53"><a href="https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/news-events">News &amp; Events</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="newsletter-container">
    <div id="newsletter">
        ...etc...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace '$' with 'jQuery'. Then it will work, and place your code below `wp_head()` section.

And try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#menu-item-63').find('a').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); // Use this to stop the default behavior of anchor.
         jQuery('#newsletter-container').toggle();
     }); // Here
 });
```

Note: There is no element that have the id "#newsletter-container". So please make sure you are using right element Id.

Comment: You are using wordpress and try to run jQuery code before jquery library loaded

Answer (score 1):

Three options to solve your problem:

1. **jQuery Confilct**

   ```
     $.noConflict();
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         jQuery('#menu-item-63 > a').click(function(){
            jQuery('#newsletter-container').toggle();
         });
     });
   ```
2. **Dynamic create menu-item-63 then used**

   ```
     $(document).click('#menu-item-63 > a', function() {
            $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
         });
     });
   ```
3. **Coding mistake**

   ```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#menu-item-63 > a').click(function(){
            $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
         });
     });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the syntax error by seeing the console of your browser by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. This error must be shown there...

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-63>a').click(function(){
        $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ready` and `click` event is working.

```
    $('#menu-item-63 a').click(function(){
        $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-63 > a').click(function() {
        $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
    }
}); // You put "}" but it's supposed to be ")"
```

You also have an issue with the "subscribe" link.

```
<a href="#">Subscribe</a>
```

By default, a link does what you'd expect it to do. You set the `href` attribute to "#", so when you click on it, the browser will load the url "https://staging.venusanddiamonds.com/#," and that's not the behavior you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu-item-63 > a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop the browser from performing the default action on the anchor
        $('#newsletter-container').toggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many JavaScript libraries/plug-ins referenced in your site, like stated above, you could be having jQuery conflicts. You can try replacing the "$" with "jQuery" like below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#menu-item-63 > a').click(function(){ 
        jQuery('#newsletter-container').toggle(); 
    }); 
});
```

Also, you should always reference the jQuery library before any other JavaScript libraries or plug-ins because those sites may depend on jQuery as well.